# Get clients telephone number

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, qml

How can I get phone number of client's cell phone in QML?

Not a phone number of someone in users contact list.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no knowledge of the client's phone number stored in the phone. Some operators may include it into SIM card, but not all. If you want to use client's phone number then he must provide it. For verification you could create and send a SMS to the same number and try to catch it. If it returns then the number is correct otherwise it might be incorrect or just delayed or phone is misconfigured and sending failed.

Comment: looks like you're right, thats strange, I always thought that such thing must be base of mobile SDK's... pitty